# Is there a way to encode object constructors with the JSON Perl Module?

Tags: perl, json

All,

I'm using the [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.27/) Perl module to encode JSON.

I'd like the resulting JSON to include lines like this:

```
{
   "startDate": new Date(2010,11,15,0,0),
   "aString"  : "String Data",
   "aNumber"  : 1234
}
```

In order to create that, I have a Perl HASHREF like this:

```
{
   startDate => SEE BELOW,
   aString   => "String Data",
   aNumber   => 1234,
}
```

Here's my problem: I can't figure out how to coerce the JSON module into printing unquoted strings, so that I can include my `new Date(...)` instantiation call. I've tried creating a Perl module with a TO_JSON method, but the output still gets quoted.

Does anybody out there have any suggestions on how I can encourage JSON to print unquoted strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON is not meant to encode objects like that. It encodes simple data structures like arrays and hashes.  If you then want to use that deserialized data to populate a blessed object, you need to add another layer on top.

For [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) objects, the plugin [MooseX::Storage](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Storage) is built for expressly this purpose.

Comment: @Bipedal: MooseX::Storage is set up to use JSON; if you're asking about something else, hop on to irc.perl.org #moose and we can help you find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is invalid in JSON. See http://www.json.org/ for what is an valid value in JSON. 
I'd return the date as an array and then use that in you js handler to create the Date object.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the Simile Timeline at [http://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/wiki/Timeline_EventSourceJSON_jsDate]. When I reread it, I noticed the 'invalid JSON' comment... I'll rethink my approach. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should rethink your approach to this problem, say, by leaving the JSON module alone but post-processing its output? For example, come up with some convention to show that the receiver should do something special with the input:

```
{
   "startDate": "EVAL:new Date(2010,11,15,0,0)",
   "aString"  : "String Data",
   "aNumber"  : 1234
}
```

Let the receiver (Perl? JavaScript?) look for hash values that start with the keyword `"EVAL:"` and perform further processing on that value.